# Can i use c/c++ to communicate with a hardware device?

Tags: c++, c, operating-system

i was wondering if its possible to use c/c++ to communicate with a hardware device such as a pci card just like a windows application would?

Or this type of thing too hard for an individual to do alone?

I have tried reading about it, but couldn't find a lot of information on the topic.

If there is no simple answer, maybe some links to examples etc would be great.

Thanks so much

Aiden

Comment: It is possible for sure. Are you talking about speaking straight "to the metal" on Windows/Linux/an embedded system/your own OS/...?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you want to communicate it.  If you want to control it specifically (dependent on this type of hardware), this is not an application thing, but a driver thing, i.e. you will have to write a driver.  This is the most likely way (since you are referring to Windows application).

If you want to talk to it in a generalized way (lets say you have a PCI card with a communication port and you want to interact with that port, no matter what manufacturer made it), you will have to see what interface (API) the operating system offers to interact with that type of device.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible,
 hovever you need to look at the devices specification, to see how.
Sometimes you just need to make direct-x/system calls, and windows will handle the rest, or you need to wrap the driver and talk trough it. 
But there is no simple answer here im afraid, it all depend on the specific card, and it's driver.

So either post the card specs, or do some research on it.